# How can i display the row and col for each text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four text boxes. I want to be able to click on the select statement on top and to the left of them and after I click on them, it should display 1,1(first text box) 1,2(second text box) 2,1(third text box) 2,2 (fourth text box). Is there a way to do this with jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#date1, #date2, #name1, #name2").change(function () {

     var myRow = $("#date1").attr("col");
     var myRow = $("#date2").attr("col");

     var myCol = $("#name1").attr("row");
     var myCol = $("#name2").attr("row");

     alert(myRow + myCol);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><select id="date1" class="allDates" col ="1"><option value="c">c</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="a">a</option></select></td>
 <td><select id="date2" class="allDates" col ="2"><option value="c">c</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="a">a</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><select id="name1" class="allNames" row = "1"><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option><option value="Joe">Joe</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="divResult" readonly="readonly" ></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="divResult2" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><select id="name2" class="allNames" row = "2">><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="divResult" id="divResult" readonly="readonly" ></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="divResult" id="divResult" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you needed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // If you want to init text before the the change, uncomment the code below
    // refreshText(); 
    $("#date1, #date2, #name1, #name2").change(function () {
        refreshText(); 
    });
});

function refreshText(){
    var name1 = $("#name1").val();
    var name2 = $("#name2").val();
    var date1 = $("#date1").val();
    var date2 = $("#date2").val();
    $("#divResult").val(name1+","+date1);
    $("#divResult2").val(name1+","+date2);
    $("#divResult3").val(name2+","+date1);
    $("#divResult4").val(name2+","+date2);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><select id="date1" class="allDates" col ="1"><option value="c">c</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="a">a</option></select></td>
 <td><select id="date2" class="allDates" col ="2"><option value="c">c</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="a">a</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><select id="name1" class="allNames" row = "1"><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option><option value="Joe">Joe</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="divResult" readonly="readonly" ></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="divResult2" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><select id="name2" class="allNames" row = "2">><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="divResult3" id="divResult3" readonly="readonly" ></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="divResult4" id="divResult4" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```